# Why does Fail2ban not send mail for one particular jail?

Tags: email, fail2ban

Fail2ban is doing it's job and `fail2ban-client status` is showing me they're all working fine and offending addresses get blocked.

When an address is blocked I like to receive a mail. That's working for all jails except for one. Why?

Here are the relevant parts of /etc/fail2ban/jail.local:

```
# My own domain is here, not example.com, obviously.
sender = Fail2Ban@example.com

banaction = iptables-multiport
mta = sendmail

action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

action = %(action_mwl)s

# This one is working. Others are as well.
[postfix]
enabled  = true
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission
filter   = postfix
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log

# This one is not working.
[recidive]
enabled  = true
filter   = recidive
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 5
```

Here is the output of `fail2ban-client status recidive` (a bit anonymized):

```
Status for the jail: recidive
|- filter
|  |- File list:        /var/log/fail2ban.log
|  |- Currently failed: 34
|  `- Total failed:     270
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 9
   |  `- IP list:       195.154.237.*** 91.200.12.*** 195.154.255.***
   `- Total banned:     12
```

Postfix:

```
Status for the jail: postfix
|- filter
|  |- File list:        /var/log/mail.log
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed:     1058
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:
   `- Total banned:     162
```

postfix.conf:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf
[Definition]

_daemon = postfix/smtpd

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 554 5\.7\.1 .*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 450 4\.7\.1 : Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<> to=<> proto=ESMTP helo= *$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: VRFY from \S+\[<HOST>\]: 550 5\.1\.1 .*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)simproper command pipelining after \S+ from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]:?$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sNOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from (.*)\[<HOST>\]: 454 4\.7\.1\.*
ignoreregex =
```

recidive.conf:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
_daemon = fail2ban\.actions
_jailname = recidive

failregex = ^(%(__prefix_line)s|,\d{3} fail2ban.actions%(__pid_re)s?:\s+)WARNING\s+\[(?!%(_jailname)s\])(?:.*)\]\s+Ban\s+<HOST>\s*$
```

From /var/log/fail2ban.log:

```
2016-12-15 08:01:52,620 fail2ban.actions[18430]: WARNING [wordpress-soft] Unban 160.202.163.***
2016-12-15 08:01:59,649 fail2ban.actions[18430]: WARNING [wordpress-soft] Ban 160.202.163.***
2016-12-15 08:02:00,610 fail2ban.actions[18430]: WARNING [recidive] Ban 160.202.163.***
2016-12-15 08:12:00,587 fail2ban.actions[18430]: WARNING [wordpress-soft] Unban 160.202.163.***
```

So I am positive Fail2ban's mail function is working. And all jails are working. There seems to be no difference between recidive and the other jails. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I have 2 jails going, the ssh and recidive.  The ssh jail was sending me emails perfectly, but nothing from recidive.  I am running:

```
Fail2Ban v0.8.13
```

My relevant global config is identical to what you posted:

```
 banaction = iptables-multiport
 mta = sendmail

 action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
                   %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

 action = %(action_mwl)s
```

My initial recidive jail config (which was not sending emails):

```
[recidive]

enabled  = true
filter   = recidive
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
#action   = iptables-allports[name=recidive]
#           sendmail-whois-lines[name=recidive, logpath=/var/log/fail2ban.log]

bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 604800
#findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 3
```

Note that I had commented out the default recidive action.  At least for me, that was what came as the default.  I did this because I wanted the recidive emails to work like the ssh, which also used the default action.  With this config... I got nothing.  Crickets.  But the recidive jail did work.  I don't know exactly what the issue was, but I knew I had to fix it.  So, I first tried uncommenting the action.  Then, it still worked, but no emails.  Or, so I thought.  Turned out the emails were going to the local root account.  I found them in the /var/mail/[user] mailbox, which I had root mail forwarded to.  So, then I realized that was because destemail was not  being used in this default action.  So, what I ended up doing was just copying the global default action_mwl & tweaked it to take the port out.

So my final recidive jail config, which worked:

```
enabled  = true
filter   = recidive
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
#action   = iptables-allports[name=recidive]
#           sendmail-whois-lines[name=recidive, logpath=/var/log/fail2ban.log]
action = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
```

Perhaps this is all by design or an old bug - I don't know.  But this is how I got it to work.  This may be too late to help you, but maybe it will help the next one in the same boat...

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. The Recidive jail just mailed me its first notification :) Glad to see the problem was not caused by me not reading the man files well enough ;)